# Fetch joined table when creating a new entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I have a `Customers` table that has `AddressEmbedded` in it.

I also have a hardcoded table `Countries` where I already have a region for every country, country is the primary key.

I want to join `AddressEmbedded` and `Countries` so I used the `ManyToOne` and put `CountryEntity` in `AddressEmbedded`.

But I'm getting an error that mapstruct can't generate `setCountry`.

So the question is, how do I make `AddressEmbedded.setCountry(string country)`? 
It's supposed to do a call to the db to get the corresponding region for that country, but it seems wrong to add a db call in a setter.

Here are the entity definitions:

```java
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public class AddressEmbedded {

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "country")
        private CountryEntity country;
    }
```

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Countries")
    public class CountryEntity {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;

        @Column(name = "region")
        private String region;
    }
```

```java
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Customers")
    public class CustomerEntity {
        @Embedded
        private AddressEmbedded address;
    }
```

Comment: You won't be able to pass ```String``` to ```AddressEmbedded.setCountry```.  It looks like you need to lookup ```CountryEntity``` by ID (```country```) and then pass it to ```AddressEmbedded.setCountry```.

Comment: A lookup in a setter?

Comment: I personally believe it's bad practice to place any logic to getters/setters. Related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600536/is-it-bad-design-if-we-add-logic-in-getter-and-setter-of-entity-class

Comment: Of course, that's why I asked this question, I don't want to add a db call in the setter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was solved with mapstruct mappings

```java
    @Mappings(
            @Mapping(target = "address.country", source = "countryEntity")
    )
    CustomerEntity fromSubmitCustomerDetailsRequestToCustomerEntity(SubmitCustomerDetailsRequest request, CountryEntity countryEntity);

    @Mappings(
            @Mapping(target = "address.country", source = "customerEntity.address.country.country")
    )
    GetCustomerDetailsResponse fromCustomerEntityToGetCustomerDetailsResponse(CustomerEntity customerEntity);
```

I have the `CountryEntity` in `fromSubmitCustomerDetailsRequestToCustomerEntity` because before I call it I validate that I have a country that exists.